# Display a weekly view (on a different page) from a monthly calendar

Tags: sharepoint-designer, web-part, sharepoint-calendar, page-viewer-web-part

On Home page, I have a monthly calendar.  On--what we'll call--page 2, I want to display just the current week from the calendar.

Using a link to a view I created ( /Lists/CoName Calendar/Weekly02.aspx ) I've managed to display the current week in a Page Viewer web part on page 2.  But, none of the data from the Home page calendar is coming through.

Answer (score 0):

Can you please try with lighting conductor web part which is free of cost we can show up multiple calender or sites or list with filter views and columns.
https://www.google.co.in/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0ahUKEwiF6Kut1PTTAhWIP48KHbLPDQYQFggmMAA&url=https%3A%2F%2Flightningtools.com%2Fproducts%2Flightning-conductor-web-part-2013%2F&usg=AFQjCNHzKFLpF1fZPDFROaQjlyOaLkHrNw&sig2=v_Vc3Ecw88XS0nVY10Ws0w

Answer (score 0):

You shouldn't need a page viewer for this. If you have a working view that displays the current week, just add a page and use the your calendar list web part to display the view. (Go the properties page for the web partafter adding the web part, while in edit mode for the page. There you will find an option to select which view to display.)

If the view isn't displaying records, please post what you're using for filters.